# Datastage REST API Error "Unrecognized SSL message"

Tags: ssl, api

I keep getitng the following issue when trying to connect to a REST API using DataStage 11.7:

> CDIER0961E: The REST step is unable to invoke the REST service, cause=javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

The scenario is as follows:
I need to retrieve a token to be used in all following calls to the API.
The retrieval of the token is done using the POST method, where custom headers are set up, and the body of the request contains the credentials to connect to the API. This is then posted and the API issues a response with the token.

After liaising with the developer of the API, the content for the request was established to be in the correct format, and the SSL certificate added to the keystore, none of which made a difference in the issue.

Has anyone ever encountered an issue like this, and could could advise on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue myself.
It was a TLS/SSL version issue, where DataStage used a much older version of TLS/SSL than the server I was connecting to.
The JVM used the newest version, and I overrode the default version used by DataStage by adding the following optional arguments in the Hierarchical Stage:

**-Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true -Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultProtocol=TLSv12**

As long as your request is in the correct format, the server should return a 200 response.